# ¿Como puedo mostrar un arreglo de string separado y con sus valores?

Tags: java, string, funciones, array

Estoy trabajando con mulestudio y tengo un string que es grande e hice un arreglo de el ya que al llamar el string para imprimirlo o me da errores o me muestra todo desordenado y lo que quiero es mostrar cada variable con su valor por separado, pero no tengo idea de como puedo hacer para mostrar cada valor del string por separado con su respuesta.

Este es el String.

```
DATOS: 
Central: xxx, 
IP dslam: 11.111.11.111, 
IP bras: 111.11.1.111, 
COID: 1111, 
Rack: 11, 
SubRack: 11, 
Slot_dslam: 11, 
Port_dslam: 1, 
Dslam_provider: 1111X, 
Community: xxxxxxx, 
Virtual_rack: 11 , 
Virtual_subrack: 11, 
SVLAN: 111, 
CVLAN: 1111, 
Erxslot: 1, 
Erxcard: 1, 
Erxport: 1,  
Provider_BRAS: XXXX, 
Model_BRAS:XX11, 
Nombre_BRAS:xxx-xxx-11, 
DSLAMPORTID: 111111 
Datos:, xxxxx, 1111, 111, XXXX, xxxx
physical (xxxxx)= 1, 
admin (xxxx)= 1, 
Profile_XXX= 11 --->Invalid Profile 
Velocidades(xxxx): 
DOWN= 111,
 UP = 111
```

Lo que quiero en teoria es hacer un arreglo que me devuelva cada variable por asi decirlo con su valor.

Ejemplo:

```
Central xxx
IP dslam 11.111.11.111
IP bras 111.11.1.111
```

Y asi con cada uno quitando los ":" y la "," para que se vea mas limpio.

Tengo algo asi (la variable objeto tiene el arreglo de string)

```
String[] objeto = this.readHTMLData(boss_RP);
             for (int i = 0 ; i < objeto.length ; i++) {

                 LoggerClass.LogDebugSevice(response.infogenerico.getServiceInfo(), i+" "+objeto[i]);   
                }

private String[] readHTMLData(String objeto) {
        String delimitadores= "\\s*,\\s*";  
        String[] arrayObjetos = objeto.split(delimitadores); 


    return arrayObjetos;
```

Esto me medio funciona pero me imprime los variables sin los valores y con los ":". (obviar lo que trae el boss_RP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si realizas un split de tu string que contiene los valores mediante el separador "," , generas un array:

```
 String[] valores = datos.split(",");
```

posteriormente reemplaza ":" por string vacio y obtendras la variable separada por su valor:

```
 for (String s : valores){
      s = s.replace(":", "");
      System.out.println(s);
  }
```

de esta forma obtendrías:

```
Central xxx 
IP dslam 11.111.11.111 
IP bras 111.11.1.111 
COID 1111 
...
...
...
```

Puedes ver este ejemplo **[online](https://ideone.com/xyke2y)**

Comment: no me sirve, ya lo probe y me sigue pasando lo mismo me imprime sin imprimir los valores de las variables. @Jorgesys

Comment: como es eso de "me imprime sin imprimir los valores de las variables"???

Comment: Osea cuando veo el log. me muestra 
`Central:
IP dslam:
IP bras: 
COID: 
...
...
...
`
Sin imprimir lo que trae cada variable por asi decirlo. @Jorgesys

Comment: Revisa el ejemplo https://ideone.com/xyke2y el cual imprime la variable y su valor

Comment: Gracias ya lo acomode @Jorgesys ya imprime :)

Comment: Excelente Miguel, solo asegura que los valores estén separados por "," para que se impriman correctamente.